# Invalid length passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

We have a stored procedure that has been working up to this point.  Recently it has started to fail due to: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

```
,case 
     when LEFT(MCTN.MCTN_NAME,2) = '  ' then SUBSTRING(MCTN.MCTN_NAME,3,LEN(MCTN.MCTN_NAME) - 2) 
     when ASCII(LEFT(MCTN.MCTN_NAME,1)) BETWEEN 32 AND 47 THEN SUBSTRING(MCTN.MCTN_NAME,2,LEN(MCTN.MCTN_NAME) - 1)      
     else MCTN.MCTN_NAME 
 end as MCTN_NAME
```

I am trying to determine how to correct this so it does not happen in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms? (You're using product specific functionality here.)

Comment: The reason is most likely that there is one or more rows that have values that are either too short or null.

Comment: microsoft sql server.  I just checked and I do have a blank value in the table for MCTN_NAME.  How can i adjust the code to ignore blank values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you have values where the length is becoming 0, such as `'  '` or one character between 32 and 47.

You can fix this by adding more conditions to the `case`:

```
(case when MCTN.MCTN_NAME LIKE '  _%'
      then SUBSTRING(MCTN.MCTN_NAME, 3, LEN(MCTN.MCTN_NAME) - 2) 
      when ASCII(LEFT(MCTN.MCTN_NAME, 1)) BETWEEN 32 AND 47 AND LEN(MCTN.MCTN_NAME) >= 2
      then SUBSTRING(MCTN.MCTN_NAME, 2, LEN(MCTN.MCTN_NAME) - 1)      
      else MCTN.MCTN_NAME 
 end) as MCTN_NAME
```

Comment: thanks! this helped.  Can i ask why you used an underscore with a wildcard in the case statement? ex. "  _%" i haven't come across that before.

Comment: @USER_NAME . . . The underscore in `like` matches any single character.  It was simply easier to type than the expression you had followed by a `len()` condition.